# How to tweak default JSON serializer in WCF REST

Tags: wcf, json, wcf-rest

WCF REST service works great in a way that it will reply/accept JSON or XML depending on header.

I want to tweak built-in JSON serializer a little so it encodes/decodes Byte[] little different. More specifically, I want to use Base64 for that.

Is that any pointers/samples where I can set custom type serializer that will affect whole service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/05/03/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters.aspx shows how to replace the default JSON serializer (DataContractJsonSerializer) with a custom one (in this case, JSON.NET).

Comment: I see that it was done for older WCF. I'm using .NET 4 WCF rest and there is no attributes involved. code is very clear an transparent. I wonder if there any way to setup serializer somewhere in web.config?

Comment: You can create a behavior extension (info at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx) to add it in config, but you still need the code to plug it in to the WCF pipeline as of 4.0. With the new WCF Web APIs (currently in preview at http://wcf.codeplex.com) it will be a lot easier (you'd write a media type formatter and plug it in using the factory).

Answer (score 0):

I just succeeded swapping out the default DataContractJsonSerializer with JSON.NET serializer in my WCF REST services 4.0 using [NETFx Json.NET MediaTypeFormatter](http://nuget.org/packages/netfx-WebApi.JsonNetFormatter) . Also see [JSON.NET Serializer for WCF REST Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827933/json-net-serializer-for-wcf-rest-services) for the solution to a problem I ran into to get this working.