# WCF REST JSON with ISO Date Format

Tags: asp.net, json, wcf, rest, datetime-format

I got into a big problem supporting ISO dateformat with JSON in my WCF Web service ( Framework 4.0 ).
I tried a lot, but no luck yet.

Rest Service :

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/{mvnoid}/{OrderID}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public DataContracts.Feedback InsertOrder(string mvnoid,string OrderID,OrderRequest orderRequest)
    {            

        OrderRequestManager orderProcessor = new OrderRequestManager();
        DataContracts.Feedback feedback = orderProcessor.ProcessOrder(orderRequest);

        return feedback;

    }
```

This is my object:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = NamespacesHelper.SCHEMA_NAMESPACE)]
public class OrderRequest
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string SystemId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)]
    public string OrderType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 3)]
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 4)]
    public DateTime OrderScheduleDate { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Order = 5)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }


}
```

This is my JSON Payload

{
"SystemId":"2",
"OrderType":"TESTORDER",
"OrderDate":"/Date(1255131630400)/",
"OrderScheduleDate":"/Date(1255131630400)/",
"UserId":150
}
And I need this "/Date(1255131630400)/" to be in ISO format "2012-10-30T15:00:00".

I tried this solution too. with creating custom JSON formatter.
[JSON.NET Serializer for WCF REST Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827933/json-net-serializer-for-wcf-rest-services).
But I was unable to find HttpHostConfiguration class anywhere . :(

Thanks in Advance for helping.

Comment: Just return that date as a string (two fields on your object, or DateTime, one string representation)?

Comment: I have date field as datetime.

Comment: Add another readonly "[DataMember] string xxxDateString {get {return xxxDate.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy" ;}}" or similar? If OrderDate for example is only coming FROM the back-end, then you don't need to expose this as a DateTime at all to WCF.

Comment: My service is called by a third party with iso format. I have used this objectrequest class in several other services, so it is not possible to change the contract.

Comment: Do you want payload to be in ISO format? What's you client in this case?