# JSON datetime format issue with .net rest service

Tags: .net, json, web-services, rest

My client is posting an object to .net rest service. In the object one property is a datetime. 
Client is posting datetime values as

> 2012-11-16T17:30:53.000Z

because of that i am getting a 400 bad request. when i capture the json object and change the datetime format to

> /Date(928164000000-0400)/

I am getting 200 ok.

I don't want to fix the client because my options are limited. Is there any standard way in .net rest service to receive the datetime as string as represented above. 
Most of the example on web are with HTTP GET so client formats it later once it receives the datetime on client side.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#json_dates - Could you not change the DateFormatHandler on the service?

Comment: Not sure how to use it here? I am not using web api

Comment: Just to clarify, what are you using, just so I can be sure?

Comment: I am using WCF Rest services. My client is salesforce

Comment: Looking around, it is a common problem. Many suggest handling it as a string and then parsing the format on the service. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134978/wcf-rest-json-with-iso-date-format - Worth a go?

Comment: unfortunately it is using its own servicehostfactory. we have our own custom WebServiceHostFactory. I need a way to JsonSerilizer into this.