# Converting/Casting List<string> to List<ulong>

Tags: c#, string, list, casting, ulong

I've been trying to cast `List<string>` property to `List<ulong>` property. It seems no matter what I do, it keeps failing to get or set data.

```
public List<string> _DocumentIds { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

Things I've tried to convert `List<string>` to `List<ulong>`:

**Using ConvertAll**

```
public List<ulong> DocumentIds 
{ 
  get => _DocumentIds.ConvertAll(x => UInt64.Parse(x)); 
  set => _DocumentIds = value.ConvertAll(x => $"{x}"); 
}
```

**Using Casts**

```
public List<ulong> DocumentIds 
{ 
   get => _DocumentIds.Cast<ulong>().ToList(); 
   set => _DocumentIds = value.Cast<string>().ToList(); 
}
```

**Using Select**

```
public List<ulong> DocumentIds
{
   get => _DocumentIds.Select(x => UInt64.Parse(x)).ToList();
   set => _ = value.Select(x => $"{x}").ToList();
}
```

**Something I'm not proud of**

```
public List<ulong> DocumentIds
{
   get
   {
      var Values = new List<ulong>();
      foreach (var Value in _DocumentIds) Values.Add(UInt64.Parse(Value));
      return Values;
   }
   set => _DocumentIds = value.Cast<string>().ToList();
}
```

I've used breakpoints on get set statements and it always hit get twice but never hits set.

Comment: Every time you retrieve `DocumentIds`, you get a new list, and you haven't written code that would let those modifications be reflected in `_DocumentIds`. Are you looking to keep those two lists synchronised?

Comment: where you storing a list of string instead of ulong?

Comment: Why not just store it as a `List<ulong>` and convert to string outside the class / when you need to? Trying to keep two lists of the same data inside the same class in sync is a bad code smell and will probably fall down as some point

Comment: Woops. @hvd Yes. I'm wanting to keep those synced.
@KenTucker & @Rhumbori Apparently, my database changes the last 2 numbers of ulong to random numbers. 

`public string _ChatterChannel { get; set; }
[JsonIgnore]
        public ulong ChatterChannel { get => UInt64.TryParse(_ChatterChannel, out ulong Id) ? Id : 0; set => _ChatterChannel = $"{value}"; }`

Comment: Perhaps you could use `ConvertingList<string, ulong>` to present the `List<string> _DocumentIds` to consumers of your container class as an `IList<ulong>` that is automatically synced to the underling `List<string>`?

Comment: @Yucked Then `List<T>` is out of the question for at least one of the two lists. It simply does not provide the support for that. A custom collection type can work, but it takes a bit of work to create. Based on your comment, I *think* it may be possible to avoid a need for this entirely: you could have a `List<T>` where `T` is a class or structure type containing `ulong` and `string` properties. Would that work for you, or do you really need `List<ulong>` and/or `List<string>`?

Comment: @dbc and hvd I was hoping that by doing DocumentIds.Contains(012345678901234) it would check _DocumentIds in the background by converting the ulong to a string then returning the result. Or if I were to do DocumentIds.Add(SomeUlongVar); it would save it to _DocumentIds. DocumentId would be working more like a converter that'd be converting values in _DocumentIds<string> to ulongs. Like the code I posted in the comments showing how I was handling the other string -> ulong properties.

Comment: @Yucked - forgot to link to the answer containing `ConvertingList<>`: it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27912461/3744182).

Comment: @Yucked Sorry, `List<T>` just doesn't support that. It doesn't allow any special actions to be performed when modifying the list. It doesn't allow any conversions to be performed when checking the list. The first option I mentioned, by "a custom collection type" was pretty much the same as that `ConvertingList<,>`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read through it. @dbc
@hvd Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks as well. I'll see if I can figure something out with `ConvertingList<,>`